# When I used Bootstrap and tried to make the site responsive the space between columns is gone.How do I fix that?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When applying Bootstrap my flex between boxes have gone I want to make it like image 2 and add spaces between boxes/div

```css
.alignboxes{
    padding-top:40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.box1,.box2,.box3,.box4,.box5,.box6 {
    background-color: white;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row alignboxes"> 
        <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box1"><img src="images/onlinesadqah.png" alt=""width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box2"><img src="images/welfare.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box3"><img src="images/medical.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box4"><img src="images/Dastarkhwan.png" alt=""width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box5"><img src="images/ROPLANT.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box6"><img src="images/education.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

image 1 with bootstrap:
[image: image 1 with bootstrap]

image 2 before bootstrap:
[image: image 2 before bootstrap]

Comment: add margin to the box elements

Comment: i dont know why margins are not working and not even flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to tweak `alignboxes` and add margin to box css -:

```css
.alignboxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
.box1,.box2,.box3,.box4,.box5,.box6 {
    background-color: white;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row alignboxes"> 
        <div class="box1"><img src="images/onlinesadqah.png" alt=""width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class="box2"><img src="images/welfare.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class="box3"><img src="images/medical.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class="box4"><img src="images/Dastarkhwan.png" alt=""width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class="box5"><img src="images/ROPLANT.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
        <div class="box6"><img src="images/education.png" alt="" width="70px" height="70px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a working solution.

Comment: @Dharman when the answer is the *same*, then it's a spam. If you post a first answer without the needed detail and instead of editing it you add another one to complete the detail then you are spaming the answer section.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is still not spam. It might warrant deletion and you can use a custom moderator message to let mods know about this, but it is not spam.

Comment: @Dharman that's what I commented *either edit the old one or remove it*

Comment: @Dharman @TemaniAfif  I have explained the reason why I wrote a new answer -:
`@TemaniAfif I have flagged below answer and requested a moderator attention. So I have not removed it, also please ask the reason before declaring the answer spam`
Please check the 2nd comment.

Comment: @AbhisarTripathi You can delete an answer if you are the author. For us the recommended way is to flag so that a moderator can remove it. However, it really needs to be almost exactly the same answer to warrant deletion. I came here because someone mentioned spam, but I do not see any spam around. Spam would be for example a link to your software, blog or some other unwanted solicitation. As I see it, there's nothing a mod needs to do here, other then cleaning all of our comments. If you wanted to edit the old answer instead of posting again, you will remember to click the edit button now :)

Comment: yess @TemaniAfif  mentioned spam, also I have deleted the old answer which initially need mod attention 27 mins back

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra div inside and consider the use of margin like below:

```css
.alignboxes {
  padding-top: 40px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.alignboxes > * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.alignboxes > * > * {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 200px;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row alignboxes">
    <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/30/30.jpg" class="m-auto"></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/30/30.jpg" class="m-auto" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/30/30.jpg" class="m-auto" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/30/30.jpg" class="m-auto" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/30/30.jpg" class="m-auto" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-offset-2 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/30/30.jpg" class="m-auto" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```